# Backbone - log results of Model to the console

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to Backbone and am trying to understand how to use it to fetch data with ajax.

I am trying to log the data to the console but am not sure how.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    name : 'undefined'
  },

  url : 'https://api.github.com/users/xxxxxxx'
});

var my = new MyModel();

//logs all the properties of fetch(). How can I get only the data?
console.log(my.fetch());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) doesn't return the model at all, it returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR):

> **fetch** `model.fetch([options])`
>
> Resets the model's state from the server by delegating to *Backbone.sync*. Returns a *jqXHR*.

The actual model data is stored in [`my.attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes):

> **attributes** `model.attributes`
>
> The **attributes** property is the internal hash containing the model's state [...].

and that's usually accessed via [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON):

> **toJSON** `model.toJSON([options])`
>
> Return a shallow copy of the model's *attributes* for JSON stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for augmentation before being sent to the server.

but, as you know, `fetch` is an AJAX call so `my.attributes` and `my.toJSON()` won't give you anything useful until the underlying AJAX call completes. The easiest way to detect that is to use the `success` callback option to `fetch`:

```
my.fetch({
    success: function(my) {
        console.log('Fetch worked: ', my.toJSON());
    }
});
```

There's also an `error` callback you can use. Alternatively, you could use the `done`, `fail`, or `always` functions on the `jqXHR`:

```
my.fetch().always(function(data, status) {
    console.log('fetch finished: ', status, my.toJSON());

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation.  I am really just beginning to learn backbone and this is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code to check the data:

```
my.fetch({
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```